# Using arrows to navigate a page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, netflix, remote-control

So the situation is that I have a media PC (Ubuntu, kodi, mythtv, chrome) and I have a chrome launcher for things like netflix to open up. However, this creates an issue when trying to browse with the remote (using an xbox 360 media remote).

I think the easiest way to get around this would be somehow be able to use the arrow and OK keys to navigate around different elements on the site (so in the main screen the different shows/movies, and in them the different episodes etc). There are 2 ways I see to approach this:

1) A generic solution. This means it would work for all websites, and may be a page with javascript that loads the required webpage into a frame or something similar, or it may be a chrome extension.

2) A site specific option. So code written just to be run on the netflix page and could be run from something like CJS (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en).

I think one of the hardest things would be to work out where elements are on the page to be able to go left/right as well as up/down.

Any ideas?